# PrestaShop - changing order status

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm currently developing payment module for PrestaShop and I'm fighting with statuses. Status with id 3 is 'Processing in progress' and it seems I have to hard code it like that:

```
$order = new Order($orderId);
$order->setCurrentState(3);
```

The problem is... can those ID's vary? Like in different prestashop installation or after little reconfiguration status with id 3 can be completely different. Does anyone knows if there is any constant defined in the prestashop via which I could fetch the id of 'Processing in progress' status?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Processing in progress` is a default order state and its ID will not change, unless you change it directly in database which I don't know why you would do that.

You could however retrieve a configuration value `PS_OS_PREPARATION` instead of hardcoding a number to get that order state ID.

```
$order = new Order($orderId);
$order->setCurrentState((int)Configuration::get('PS_OS_PREPARATION'));
```

You can find other default order state IDs in config by looking into the `configuration` table and find rows with `name` column that have `PS_OS_` prefix.